# Error in TLS handshake when using mutual authentication

Tags: android, security, ssl, https, certificate

While testing my app (https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.degoo.android) I've found that on some devices the TLS handshake between the app and our servers fail if the https request requires a client certificate (i.e. mutual authentication). The same code works on Windows and on OS X, so I know that it's not caused by an incorrect cert or that I have forgotten to include the cert into the SSLContext. I have detected it on both some Android 4.4 devices and on some 5.0 devices. Unfortunately I haven't found any common denominator which causes it to fail (other than Android). However, on devices were it fails it fails 100% of the time.

I've analyzed the network traffic to see more precisely when the error occurs. The following thing works on all devices:

1. The connection is established and the client successfully validates the server's certs.
2. The client sends it's HTTP request.
3. The server detects that the request is for protected area and sends a certificate_request.
4. The client decides which client certificate to send (we can see that it selects the correct certificate) and sends it.

After the client has responded with its certificate it sends two more TLS records and then the handshake fails.

Here's an example of how what these two TLS records looks like on a device were the handshake SUCCEEDS:

```
14 03 01 00 20 9c 07 49 78 9f ba 09 03 41 6b 66 ad 46 e2 75 94 f7 cf 18 bd 11 cf 35 a2 eb 5e b8 a8 4c 2a 1d c5

16 03 01 00 30 20 0e 13 d7 48 b9 6e b2 1b 96 6f 10 56 67 81 63 d9 d8 c7 73 23 95 3b f9 da f9 ce f4 f8 d1 7e 1b a4 12 92 4c 4f 54 a5 f8 49 75 d5 46 f4 2d 29 97
```

Here's an example of how what these two TLS records looks like on a device were the handshake FAILS:

```
14 03 01 00 20 a9 86 c2 fd 03 0a f8 08 fa f8 9e eb b7 97 07 56 6f 27 c0 d6 8f 95 be 77 c1 44 84 e9 e1 56 6f 6a

16 03 01 00 30 ff 36 76 e5 47 87 84 71 1c ce c9 08 41 45 fc 09 c6 ef 08 e6 21 ff 45 3a 10 ae 8d 5a 99 5f ca c5 ac bd bf 7e ca 69 32 4d 1f 01 c6 30 83 8e 06 cb
```

From the first byte of the records I can see that both clients send a change cipher spec record and then a handshake record. A funny thing about the failing devices is that byte with index 5 of the second record has value ff. When I look in TLS specification I don't see any handshake record type with that value. The device that succeeds has that byte set to 20, which means "finished".

Any idea on what's going on? What could cause this?